# I want to separate html and css but something went wrong

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="col-md-12" style="">
<div class="col-md-4 linkdetail" class="cursor">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:40px">
        <img src="/img/product3.png" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:15px">
        <img src="/img/100G_ITAEWON 565 Copy.png" style="display:inline-block;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:30px">
        <img src="/img/$ 24.5 copy.png" style="display:inline-block;">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 linkdetail" class="cursor">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:40px">
        <img src="/img/product3.png" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:15px">
        <img src="/img/100G_ITAEWON 565 Copy.png" style="display:inline-block;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:30px">
        <img src="/img/$ 24.5 copy.png" style="display:inline-block;">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 linkdetail" class="cursor">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:40px">
        <img src="/img/product3.png" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:15px">
        <img src="/img/100G_ITAEWON 565 Copy.png" style="display:inline-block;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:30px">
        <img src="/img/$ 24.5 copy.png" style="display:inline-block;">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The code above is html+css inline source code. But I want to separate html and css. So, I've edited this code, see below.

PS I has modified it, but I think both html, css are not good. How can fix to effective source code?

What's problem this code?

```css
.cursor             { cursor:pointer; }
.first-gap          { margin-bottom:38px; }
.second-gap         { margin-bottom:36px; }
.third-gap          { margin-bottom:38px; }
.word-word-gap      { margin-bottom:15px; }
.gap                { margin-bottom:95px; }
.reactive           { display:inline-block;width:100%; }
#section>.first-one { min-height:592px; }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12" class="first-one">
<div class="col-md-6 linkdetail" class="cursor">
    <div class="col-md-12 first-gap reactive">
        <img src="/img/product1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 word-word-gap">
        100G_ITAEWON 565
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 gap">
        $ 24.5
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 linkdetail" class="cursor">
    <div class="col-md-12 first-gap reactive">
        <img src="/img/product2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 word-word-gap">
        100G_ITAEWON 565
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 gap">
        $ 24.5
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using bootstrap. You should import the CDN for it. You can refer to this site for bootstrap CDN's. Hope it helps [Bootstrap CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

Comment: but cdn is already.. TT.TT
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: did you separate the css styles and put it in the <head> part of your html?